# Can I use a .cshtml file as the LoginURL in an ASP.NET app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, config

My ASP.NET application works fine when my Forms Authentication LoginURL is an .asp page.  However, the rest of my app is in Razor, and I can't get the layout to match the other pages.  I tried replacing it with a CSHTML page, login.cshtml, but I get this error in Visual Studio:

```
Warning 2   C:\Users\ddelgrande\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects
\ABMCEditAndReports\ABMCEditAndReports\RazorLogin.cshtml:
ASP.NET runtime error: The pre-application start initialization method Start
on type System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode threw an
exception with the following error message:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..
```

The error appears once for every .CSHTML page I have open in Visual Studio.

Here are the Configuration/AppSettings values in my web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Removing the webpages key does not fix the problem.

Note that I am using MVC 3.

Is what I am trying to do even possible, and if so, how do I get around this problem?

Comment: As far as I know the cshtml shouldn't matter as long as you have your routes configured appropriately. Is your whole project razor? Or was it started as an aspx project? 


Also.. try adding this.

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

To your project/Views/web.config, not the root web.config.

Comment: The tag you suggested was already in Views/web.config.  I tried changing it to 'value="true"' to see if it would do anything different, but it didn't.

Yes, the entire project is Razor/MVC, except for the login page.

Comment: Perhaps try removing the key from both web.configs completely. Or if it is not in your main web config, try adding it to that.

Comment: I realize this may be a pain, but if you started the application as an ASPX application, then switched to using Razor (CShtml), and now you want to use Razor throughout the application. Your best bet may be to start a new MVC project and move the code into that one. There have been some obscure issues I have witnessed when changing from an aspx to a razor based UI, it is usually around the config files and what assemblies get loaded into the GAC.

Comment: If beginning a new application is an issue, ensure that you have everything structured appropriately. (While not necessary, this may help clear things up) Ensure that appropriate cshtml files are in folders under "Views" that are respective to the controllers they are working with. Make sure that you have appropriate dependentassembly tags and correct assembly versions. Be sure that your pages node in the Views/web.config is pointing at the correct version of System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: These are the app keys I have in my mvc4 razor app.

    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

Comment: MattB, your previous comment solved it - I didn't realize that I needed to have a Model and Controller for it (since I didn't need one for the ASPX version of the page).

Comment: Ah yes, with MVC there is no need for "code-behind" files which is generally what ASPX uses. Now you only need controllers and ensure that your views align with your controllers where necessary. Controllers are your code-behind but allow for RESTful actions.

Comment: Except it's not true that you need to use mvc to use razor.  Search "webmatrix razor" to see examples.

Comment: JayC, I know it's not true, but he was using MVC, so I was trying to help him with that aspect of it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need "ASP.NET Web Pages" referenced in your project, if I read this blog post right, to use `.cshtml` files as regular pages.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/07/07/how-webmatrix-razor-asp-net-web-pages-and-mvc-fit-together.aspx

This gives you a start, but it says install webmatrix (argh!).

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/getting-started

There *does* appear to be a nuget package for it if you have nuget installed.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages

Not sure if that works with mvc3, though. Hrmmm.